# How to Access "live_views" Parameter for Live Videos on Facebook and Instagram APIs?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Stack Overflow community!

I'm working on a Python project where I need to collect live streaming data from various platforms, including Facebook, Instagram, and YouTube, regarding the number of people watching at that moment. I managed to implement functionality for YouTube using the Google API Python Client, but I'm facing difficulties with the Facebook and Instagram API, specifically when trying to access the live_views parameter of live videos.

Here is the code snippet I'm using to try to access the Facebook API:

```
import requests

FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN = "MY_TOKEN_HERE"

def get_facebook_viewers(video_id):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{video_id}?fields=live_views&access_token={FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    return data.get('live_views', '0')
```

This code is supposed to return the number of live viewers for a specific video on Facebook; I want the same for Instagram. However, I'm having trouble getting a valid response from the API. Here are the details:

How can I access this API from Facebook and Instagram? Is there an easier way to make this query? Can I pull this information from any video, any live stream through the link only, or does it have to be only from the pages I own?

Thank you very much for any help!

I've attempted to use the Facebook Graph API to fetch the live_views count of live videos on Facebook by sending a GET request to the Graph API endpoint with the video ID and my access token. My expectation was to receive a JSON response containing the live_views count among other details of the live video. Specifically, I was hoping to integrate this functionality into a larger Python application that monitors live viewer statistics across multiple platforms (Facebook, Instagram, and YouTube) in real-time.

For Instagram, I'm still looking for a starting point, as their API documentation is less clear about accessing live video statistics. I was expecting a similar approach to Facebook would work, given they're under the same parent company, but I haven't found direct documentation or examples on how to achieve this.